# Windows 10 finds pip but not python

Tags: python, path, windows-10

I have done everything the documentation says to.

- I added pip path and it is working but the python command is not working. [Image of path to my python38 DLL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSGzo.png)
- The pip path which I added: `C:\Users\Harshal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts 
  python path : C:\Users\Harshal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`
- python command is not working .pip works

Comment: Add python path to PYTHON_HOME environmental variable

Comment: Did you restart/logout-login Windows after editing the system path? Did you verify the path was updated by starting a COMMAND shell and typing `PATH` and checkings its output? Post us the result of typing `PATH` in a command window (as text, not as image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your python to system environment variables like your path.

or Reinstall python and check the Add to path Checkbox while installing

```
Add to path
```

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, `py` command works as well as `python` command, so you can try `py`:

```
py -V
py -m pip # this is for pip, exactly for this python version
```